# Como puedo descargar un bills de aws en csv de amazon en java?

Tags: java, aws, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-java

Hola  a todos es la primera vez que estoy tratando de consumir un servicio de amazon y tengo una tarea que es descargar un factura de aws-

La manera manual que se hace para descargar la factura del mes es por medio del dashboard de AWS donde se selecciona bills, como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Despues se selecciona el mes que se quiere descargar y esto a la vez le dice al usuario que procesa descargar la factura en formato csv como en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mi pregunta aqui es, ¿es posible hacer la descarga de esto con el sdk java de AWS?**

Tambien habia encontrado en la documentacion del sdk AWS en java venia algo similar pero no se si sea igual que es usando ReportDefinition tengo un codigo de ejemplo que es el siguiente:

```
PutReportDefinitionRequest request = new PutReportDefinitionRequest();

AWSCostAndUsageReportClientBuilder reportBuilder = AWSCostAndUsageReportClientBuilder.standard();

AWSCostAndUsageReportClient costAndUsageReport = (AWSCostAndUsageReportClient) reportBuilder
        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds)).withRegion("us-east-1").build();

ReportDefinition reptDefinition = new ReportDefinition();

reptDefinition.setReportName("ChandraReport123");
reptDefinition.setTimeUnit("DAILY");
reptDefinition.setCompression("ZIP");

ArrayList addidtionSchemaElements = new ArrayList();
addidtionSchemaElements.add("RESOURCES");

reptDefinition.setAdditionalSchemaElements(addidtionSchemaElements);

reptDefinition.setS3Bucket("etho-onnu22");
reptDefinition.setS3Prefix("someprefix");
reptDefinition.setS3Region("us-east-1");
reptDefinition.setFormat("textORcsv");
request.setReportDefinition(reptDefinition);

PutReportDefinitionResult reportResult = costAndUsageReport.putReportDefinition(request);
```

No estoy seguro si estoy yendo de la manera correcta o esta no es la implementacion que busco para descargar el informe de la factura de aws. Alguna ayuda? estoy perdido

Comment: Con el código que adjuntas, lo que estás haciendo es creando un reporte que se guardará diariamente en S3. Como tal no vas a descargar nada. Yo realmente tampoco estoy muy familiarizado con lo que preguntas, pero yo usaría el `CostExplorerClient` para obtener el uso y el costo de lo que he consumido. Te adjunto [un ejemplo muy sencillo](https://pastebin.com/BwbPD3G7) que hice en el `SDK 2.17.192` que te muestra en la consola lo que has gastado diario en el periodo que especifiques. Tu pom debe [lucir así](https://pastebin.com/JVExzQHi). Espero que al menos eso te dé un norte.

Comment: Con eso que te adjunto, puedes hacer la petición, obtener todos los datos que necesites, y tú luego manualmente, guardar el csv con los datos que requieras. Puedes especificar el periodo, tanto diario, como mensual, como por hora. Ojalá pudiera ayudarte más. ¡Buena suerte!

Comment: Hola Jaime, gracias por el dato del codigo quehabia compartido de eso no tenia idea, entonces de lo que me pasaste lo acabo de implementar y si trae informacion pero aun asi me piden los demas datos que vienen en el facturacion o bill del ejemplo que puse como 
InvoiceId,PayerAccountId,LinkedAccountId,ProductName,SubscriptionId,UsageType,Operation, esta parte sabras donde lo puedo encontrar?

Comment: Hola Luis, pues he buscado en la documentación de la api sin éxito, e incluso leyendo [comentarios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55849494/how-can-i-get-aws-monthly-invoice-pdf-using-aws-api) en algunas preguntas de so en inglés que dicen que aún no existe manera programática de obtener los detalles de tus pagos ni facturas. Lo que se me ocurre sería, generes reportes de tus pagos, [los guardes en s3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/configurecostallocreport.html) y luego los obtengas de `S3` con un `getObject`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la informacion Jaime, seguire buscando  mas de esto que me tiene como loco